# RabbitMQ : Multiple senders for one receiver

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue, rabbitmq

I'm using rabbitMQ for my spiders, each spiders send datas to the receiver.
I started the `receiver.py` as daemon with this command : `daemon python /receiver.py`

When I start multiple instances of spider I have the feeling that there is more of one instance of `receiver.py` for the queue **"expired"**.

What is wrong with my code ?

**The sender works like this (Scrapy spider) :**

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='expired')

def parse_items(self, response):
    for link in LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), deny=self.allowed_domains, canonicalize=False).extract_links(response):
         # self.logger.info('[{}] Added to the List'.format(domain))
         channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='expired', body=domain, )
         self.domains.append(domain)
```

**The receiver do this :**

```
class Threaded_worker(threading.Thread):

    def callback(self, ch, method, properties, domain):
        url = 'http://www.checkdomain.com/cgi-bin/checkdomain.pl?domain=' + domain
        self.parse_checkdomain(url, domain)
        time.sleep(domain.count('.'))
        ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        self.channel.queue_declare(queue='expired')
        self.channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
        self.channel.basic_consume(self.callback, queue='expired')

    def run(self):
        logging.warning('Worker Start !')
        self.channel.start_consuming()


for _ in range(15):
    td = Threaded_worker()
    td.setDaemon(False)
    td.start()
```

I have a little question more by the way, if my `receiver.py` is not start, all the data are still save in the queue ?

Comment: have you found the answer?

Comment: can you share it please? I have the similar issue

Comment: @Kostanos What is your problem exactly ?

Comment: My worker look like this : http://pastebin.com/XFJQ20x4